# My computer is not recognizing my Arduino anymore

Tags: arduino-mkr1000

For some reason my Arduino is not recognized by my computer anymore. It happened while I was programming using Platform.io within Visual Studio Code, earlier today it was still possible for me to upload sketches to my computer. Unfortunately, it's not the case anymore.

I've tried many solutions, unfortunately they didn't work. These are the solutions i've tried:

1. Use Arduino IDE, instead of Platform IO to upload my Sketch;
2. Reinstall Arduino IDE and try to upload again;
3. Reinstall All Arduino software;
4. Restart my Computer without the Arduino Attached;
5. Reset my Arduino using the Reset button on the Arduino;
6. Using a different USB-cable;
7. Try the same solutions on a different Computer;
8. Update my port drivers in the Device Manager;
9. Deleted and reinstalled my port drivers in the Device Manager;
10. Manually add hardware in the Device Manager

So I've tried a lot of solutions, without any positive outcome. There is definitely something wrong with my Arduino or else it would have worked on a different computer.

Perhaps somebody recognizes this problem and will have a solution for this problem.

I am using the Arduino MKR1000.

Comment: It looks like your arduino is having a bad day.  Use a scope to check voltages, then the clock.  If there is no 5 volt or no 3.3 volt, then you will need to change a regulator (that's the most common type of  failure) , If the clock is dead, you're out of luck, and will need to change the CPU, or get a new arduino.  This happens more often than you think, it's a good idea to have a spare at all times.

Comment: What OS are you using If its windows can you see the MKR in device manager?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, so i found the solution: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=673665.0

The loopback test only works for boards that use a dedicated USB to serial adapter chip. Your MKR1000 has native USB capabilities, and thus does not use a dedicated USB to serial adapter chip. This means the loopback test will always fail on the native USB boards like your MKR1000.

If you press and release the reset button on the MKR1000 twice quickly, does the "L" LED start pulsing? After doing that, do you see a port for the MKR1000 in the Arduino IDE's Tools > Port menu?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Arduino code, and has no code, a violation of the 'Arduino' tag rules.

Comment: @TomServo There you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=673665.0

The loopback test only works for boards that use a dedicated USB to serial adapter chip. Your MKR1000 has native USB capabilities, and thus does not use a dedicated USB to serial adapter chip. This means the loopback test will always fail on the native USB boards like your MKR1000.

If you press and release the reset button on the MKR1000 twice quickly, does the "L" LED start pulsing? After doing that, do you see a port for the MKR1000 in the Arduino IDE's Tools > Port menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try it on another computer or try another Arduino. 
If the Arduino works on another computer, then your computer either has bad drivers, hardware ports or something more serious as a problem.
If the Arduino doesn't work on another computer, buy another one, or repair it if you can.